# hevc transcoded video not playing in safari

Tags: ffmpeg, hls, hevc

I transcoded a video with ffmpeg to hevc using the below command.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx265 -crf 23 -preset medium -x265-params keyint=60 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_segment_type fmp4 -hls_playlist_type vod -tag:v hvc1  -single_file 1 playlist.m3u8
```

ffmpeg version: 5.0.1

The output is playing fine in chrome but not in safari.

I found from apple support community that fmp4 should work fine in safari. I tried with different tags, presets and x265 params but I can't make it work.

I want the output to be hevc hls and it should be playable in safari and chrome. Any help is really appreciated.